# A basic example c linked lists count code always throw segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, c11

I have following code

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * File:   index.c
 * Author: nikos
 *

 * Created on May 6, 2016, 9:19 AM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 *
 */
struct people {
    int age;
    char *name;
    struct people * next;
};
typedef struct people people;

void count(people person) {
    people *current;
    people *next;
    current = &person;
    next = person.next;
    int count = 1;
    while (current) {
        printf("age : %d\n", current->age);
        printf("name : %s\n", current->name);
        count++;
        current = next;
        if (next->next != NULL) {
            next = next->next;
        } else {
            next = NULL;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    people person = {
        .name = "nikos",
        .age = 25
    };
    person.next = malloc(sizeof (people));
    person.next->age = 26;
    person.next->name = "test";
    person.next->next = NULL;
    count(person);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this it runs the loop and prints the contents of the lists, but when it hits null gives segfault.

I cannot figure out why seems to me something is wrong with c.

This is so basic logic check the content of the next if its null stop the loop else continue one more step.

Comment: Your code has no clear logic, it surely is *understandable*, but it's not clear. Use `for (current = &person ; current != NULL ; current = current->next) {printf() ... }` instead of the `while` loop, does the problem still occur.

Comment: On the second iteration of the loop, `next` is NULL - but you go ahead and dereference it with `next->next`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's what I mean, it's to complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: Passing by value like that is very unusual. I would expect a `size_t count(const Person *head);` prototype.

Comment: @unwind i pass by value because i just wanna count not edit

Comment: "something is wrong with c" - Yes, that is much more likely than you having errors in your code. Maybe reading about the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle is a good idea.

Comment: Well there is a lot of things wrong with C, but not in this specific case :) Regarding keeping things simple, there's this famous little quote by Brian Kernighan: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."

Comment: @nikoss But the called function can still "edit" the contents of all the other list elements, just not the head. Passing a constant pointer like I suggested is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write complicated code for simple things, try to write it as simple as possible. Trying to understand your code knowing that it wants to achieve a simple thing was so hard, that I immediatly saw a way of writing it that would make the logic clear and prevent any silly mistake, check this out

```
void
count(people person)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (people *node = &person ; node != NULL ; node = node->next)
    {
        printf("age : %d\n", node->age);
        printf("name : %s\n", node->name);

        count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
}

int
main(void)
{
    people person = {.name = "nikos", .age = 25};

    person.next = malloc(sizeof(people));
    if (person.next == NULL)
        return -1;

    person.next->age = 26;
    person.next->name = "test";
    person.next->next = NULL;

    count(person);

    return 0;
}
```

Your code fails, because you set `next` to `NULL`

```
next = NULL;
```

and then try to dereference it in

```
if (next->next != NULL)
```

you should check for `next == NULL` in the while conditional.

```
while ((current != NULL) && (next != NULL))
```

but that code would still be incredibly complicated und cumbersome.

See that

```
if (next->next != NULL)
    next = next->next;
else
    next = NULL;
```

has exactly the same effect as

```
next = next->next;
```

Comment: i still cannot get why my code refuses to work though

Comment: @Lundin i dont pass a pointer because i dont want to edit the actual struct i just take a copy of it nto my function and count it

Comment: @nikoss Hence `const`, to block the function from changing anything even by accident. Google "const correctness". Passing structs by value is bad practice, as it takes up execution time to copy the struct, and the copy also needlessly uses up extra stack memory.

Comment: @nikoss `const people *const` would prevent two things: 1. Altering the pointer content accidentally, 2. Reassigning the pointer accidentally. You generally should not copy anything unless you **need** a copy. That's one amazing thing about pointers.

Answer (score 2):

When you've displayed the last item in the list, next is NULL, so trying to reference next->next in the 'if' stmt is really saying NULL->next! There's your segfault.  The unnecessary complexity of the logic makes it extra hard to see, but that's what's happening.